# Use TRIM in JOIN

Tags: sql, string, oracle, join

I have the following SQL code

```
SELECT      State.CODE                    Code, 
            State.CODE1                   Code1, 
            State.CODE2                   Code2, 
            YYY.1003."BRANCH"            "Branch" 
     FROM   XXX.1002 State
            LEFT JOIN YYY.1003 
                   ON State.CODE= YYY.1003.CODE
```

Now I need a new column that shows me the field/ column "Country" from table ZZZ.100.
The key is 1002.CODE1 - ZZZ.100.CODE1

Unfortunately, ZZZ.100.CODE1 has spaces before the values (4 spaces).

How can I use the trim function (is this the right one) to get a join on 1002.CODE1 - ZZZ.100.CODE1

Comment: I just find the code so hard to read with numeric table names and aliases.  I'm a bit lost on what `ZZZ.100` is.  It is not part of your query.

Comment: Like `1002.CODE= Trim(YYY.1003.CODE)`?

Comment: Thanks @JNevill: How would you combine that join with the join above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you want:

```
select x.code, x.code1, x.code2, y.branch, z.country
from xxx.1002 x
left join yyy.1003 y on x.code= y.code
left join zzz.100  z on trim(z.code1) = x.code1
```

`trim()` removes spaces on both ends of the string. If you want to remove only leading spaces, you can do: `trim(leading ' ' from z.code1)`.

Note that I used more meaningful table aliases, in order to make the query easier to write and read.

I would also reommend against using all-digits table names: in Oracle, non-quoted identifiers must begin begin with an alphabetic character.

Answer (score 1):

First thing is why a Key column contains spaces on it? A key column should never contain spaces, it is terrible for performance. 
The point to think about here is to remove those spaces from this column

The use of TRIM, considering you are using SQL Server
In SQL Server you can use LTRIM (for left trim, remove left spaces) and/or RTRIM (for right trim, remove right spaces)

Ex: 
Select 
LTRIM(RTRIM(Table.Column))
from Table

I hope this can help you